Passing std::unique_lock() with lock held to a thread as parameter in C++11
I am trying to pass a std::unique_lock() to a std::thread as shown in the below code snippet and the application crashes with "Unlock of unowned mutex" exception when I try to unlock() the lock in the thread in MSVS
std::mutex g_mutex; // Available globally

//SomeClass.cpp`
SomeClass::func1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    //Do stuff
    AnotherClass->func2(lock);`
}

//AnotherClass.cpp
AnotherClass::func2(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock)
{
    //Do stuff
    //lock.unlock() works OK here
    thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::bind(&AnotherClass:threadFun, this, std::ref(lock)));
    return;
}

AnotherClass::threadFunc(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock)
{
    // Do stuff
    lock.unlock(); // Aborts the application with **"Unlock of unowned mutex"** here`
}

What's the issue here?
I tried passing passing the lock to the thread using std::move() and that didn't work either. I would like to know what mistake I am doing in the above code and is there better alternative to what I am doing?

A lock must be unlocked in the same thread that locked it.

Threads are already complicated enough without passing locks around. In general you don't pass lock (or mutexes around). They are usually owned by a datastructure or class.  Also using global variables is not recommended, doubly so for mutexes. Again just give AnotherClass a  member variable of type mutex to guard its own threadsafety and do the same for other classes. you will get more fine grained and more controllable locking that way. In other words your design needs improvement ;) (In general if something is hard to do, this is usually a signal to consider a different approach)

True but the objective is to block this entire operation so that other users don't start before it's finished. The application has operation1, operation2 etc and these operations can be started independently but I want to block openration2 while operation1 is running. So that's the objective hence the global mutex

The lock in func1 goes out of scope when the function returns. At that point, locks destructor is called and it will then call unlock() on the mutex.
lock.unlock(); in threadFunc also unlocks the mutex and you therefore have a double unlock, with undefined behavior as a result.
Also, you must only unlock the mutex from the thread which locked it:
std::mutex::unlock:

The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.


Thanks for the reply. The idea is to block the other users from starting this operation while it's already running. Any suggestions on how we block the entire operation?

The application has operation1, operation2 etc and these operations can be started independently but I want to block openration2 while operation1 is running

@Seektech just create the unique in the thread where you want to access the resource.
